# Autolayout issue for width equally in iOS iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

I have three views as subview as shown below with **equal width & height constraint**

[image]

**If view B has no data then it should show as below**
[image]

**My try** If iset B's width as zero then all views width will be zero.

**How to get this?**

**Thank you**

Comment: Is view B the only one who may not have data, or it may happen to any of the 3 views? Also is it possible that 2 views have no data?

Comment: What is your target iOS? Is it iOS 8.0, or an earlier version?

Comment: @robmayoff iOS 7 & iOS 8, but you can also give me answer if this only possible for iOS 8.

Comment: @pteofil, Yes you are right. All conditions should be satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What can you do is add a width constraint to it (middle one) and make is less than 2000 with priority(1000) greater than equal width(750)

Now make an outlet and the the constant of with constraint(<2000) to zero.

You can find the [sample here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4cbj4Pq1kSDY2JqNmNWc05lWFE/view?usp=sharing).

Why I have set the `2000` is because this constraint is only needed to zero the width. It shouldn't affect the width if the width is non-zero. Now as the width are equally (middle view) and it should be less than `2000` thus the view displays equally on the screen. And when I set the width constraint to zero the width of the middle view becomes zero as it's priority is higher than the equal widths.

[image]

This code sets the width of middle view to zero.

```
- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender {
  self.widthView2.constant = 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: yes, it is awesome But should I also use same login for other view?
what if only View A has Data?

Comment: You can use same logic with all the view, create width constraint for all the view and make it zero just like the middle one

Comment: what if only View A has Data?

Comment: Please explain a bit more, I'm not getting you. Do you want to just show the view A?

Comment: As I said earlier, just create the constraint for all the view, as I did for middle view and set the constant to zero for view B & C. I'll update the link for the sample if you're unable to do it.

Comment: it is breaking the constraint of View C width

Comment: I have added the latest code, please download it and have a look.

Comment: ok, thanks a lo! it is working..
I will implementing this & let you know if find any query.
also accept answer

Comment: its working awesome but I will give you bounty after only 18 hours as per stack overflow terms. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Sample link is not working, please remove it or change it.

Comment: @Kampai I've lost the old code and have updated the project

Comment: @InderKumarRathore: No worries, just a gentle reminder, thanks for new link!

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure your equal-width constraints are set up like this:

```
A.width == B.width
A.width == C.width
```

And **not** like this:

```
A.width == B.width
C.width == B.width
```

That is, make sure view B is only involved in **one** equal-width constraint.

Next, make outlets connected to view B and to the equal-width constraint on view B.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *viewB;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bEqualWidthConstraint;
```

To connect the constraint outlet, you'll need to find the constraint in the storyboard outline. It'll be one of the constraints on the nearest common ancestor of A and B; it won't be on A or B directly. When you find it in the storyboard outline, you can control-drag from it to the outlet in your source code (or you can create a new outlet by control-dragging to anywhere in your `@interface`).

Add another property to hold another constraint setting B's width to zero:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *bZeroWidthConstraint;
```

Initialize `bZeroWidthConstraint` but don't install it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.bZeroWidthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
        constraintWithItem:self.viewB attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
        toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
        multiplier:0 constant:0];
}
```

When you want to hide view B, uninstall `bEqualWidthConstraint` and install `bZeroWidthConstraint`.

On iOS 8.0, you can uninstall a constraint by setting its `active` property to `NO`, but on earlier versions, you have to send a message to the view on which the constraint is installed. That's normally the nearest common ancestor of the constrained views. Assuming the common ancestor of A and B is `viewB.superview`:

```
- (void)hideB {
    [self.viewB.superview removeConstraint:self.bEqualWidthConstraint];
    [self.viewB addConstraint:self.bZeroWidthConstraint];
}
```

Note that since `bZeroWidthConstraint` only constrains view B, you can install it directly on view B.

When you want to show view B again, uninstall `bZeroWidthConstraint` and reinstall `bEqualWidthConstraint`:

```
- (void)showB {
    [self.viewB removeConstraint:self.bZeroWidthConstraint];
    [self.viewB.superview addConstraint:self.bEqualWidthConstraint];
}
```

Comment: its awesome & working good but should I use same logic for others also?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to understand that you can give priorities to different constraints in iOS. By default the priority is 1000, which is highest.

Now, you need to give your `equalWidth` constraints a priority of 750. Secondly, you need to apply horizontal spacing from ViewA to ViewB, and ViewB to ViewC. Ideally the constant for the horizontal spacing should be 0, which will make the sides of the three views stick together.

And now, when you make the width for ViewB equal to 0, your ViewA and ViewC will take up all the space, with equal widths and ViewB will vanish.

Please let me know if you have any confusion in this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but should I hide `View B.hidden = YES` or set width constant to zero?

Comment: You need to set the width constant of ViewB to 0. 
Also, you will need one more constraint for `equalWidth` between ViewA and ViewC with a priority of 750.

Comment: not working because I set ViewA, View B & View C equal widths are priority with 1000

Comment: You will have to change the priority down to 750 then. It won't work fine with a priority of 1000 as the constraints conflict resulting in ambiguous results.

Answer (score 0):

Download the code: set constraints as per your requirements. 
[Click to Download](http://cl.ly/3r1k3Z263f0B?_ga=1.104483459.2001106650.1432806828)

create `NSLayoutConstraint _distance_ViewA_ViewC` variable for distance between `ViewA` to `ViewC`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //when viewB is hidden remove the comments
    _distance_ViewA_ViewC.constant = 8.0f;
    _viewB.hidden = true;

}
```

**OutPut**
For `viewA, viewB, viewC` 
[image]

[image]

for `viewA, ViewC` and `viewB` is **hidden**

[image]
[image]